# pandas - generate a dataframe composed of summaries of subsets of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subset

I have a pandas dataframe `df` of shape `(100, 10)` (100 rows, 10 cols), and I want to generate a dataframe `df_summary` from `df` that:

- is of shape `(1, 4)` with column names of ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']
- the 1st row contains `mean`s of `df`'s 1st col, 2-4th cols (the mean of all rows across these 3 columns), 5-8th cols and 9-10th cols
- the 2nd row contains `variance`s of `df`'s 1st col, 2-4th cols, 5-8th cols and 9-10th cols

I did my research and still don't know how to do that efficiently. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are 2 solution, first with specified ranges in list, reshape by `stack` and aggregate by [`Series.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.agg.html) with pass to [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
np.random.seed(2020)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(100, 10)))

L = [[0], range(2, 4), range(5, 8), range(8, 10)]
cols = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']

out = pd.concat([df[x].stack().agg(['mean','var']) for x in L], axis=1, keys=cols)
print (out)
          col1      col2      col3      col4
mean  4.120000  4.270000  4.580000  4.405000
var   8.793535  8.298593  7.963478  9.418065
```

Or for ranges is used [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html), unpivot by [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and then aggregate `mean` with `var`:

```
cols = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']

df.columns = pd.cut(df.columns, [0,1,5,8,11], labels=cols, include_lowest=True, right=False)

df = df.melt().groupby('variable')['value'].agg(['mean','var']).T
print (df)
variable      col1      col2      col3      col4
mean      4.120000  4.482500  4.580000  4.405000
var       8.793535  8.611222  7.963478  9.418065
```